# Regular Expression does not match correct words

Tags: regex

I have a problem. I have this regex:

```
([\w ]*[^'entre']{1}) entre ([\w ]*) y ([\w ]*)
```

And some possible strings to match are:

- av cordoba entre medrano y gascon
- esmeralda entre av rivadavia y lavalle
- av cor1doba entre entre rios y suipac2ha
- monroe entre aizpurra y av de los constituyentes

The thing is, The regular expression matches the first 3 strings, but the other is not being matched and I don't know really why

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The strings are names of streets and intersections of them. So, I want to find that expression and then replace it in the form:

*street1/street2-street3*

For the first example string, the replacement looks like

*av cordoba/medrano-gascon*

And the ^['entre] is there because a street name can contain the string "entre", and I must take it as the name of the street

**EDIT**

I found the solution. I have to use `*([\w ]*(?<!entre)) entre ([\w ]*) y ([\w ]*)*`

Thank you all

Comment: What do you think `[^'entre']` matches? It simply matches anything that's not `'`, `e`, `n`, `t` or `r`.

Comment: How about: .*entre.* ?

Comment: What about trying to understand the issue by yourself: https://regex101.com/r/oU4nP2/1 ?

Comment: to your second edit: are you sure it shouldn't be `([\w ]*(?<! entre)) entre ([\w ]*) y ([\w ]*)` (notice the space before the negative lookbehind)

Comment: Yes, becausa I'm getting that space in [\w ], notice the space after w

Comment: how then do you parse `fooentre entre foo y bla`?

Comment: Good, you're right, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$pattern = `(.*?)(?: entre )(.*?)(?: y )(.*?$)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU4nP2/3)

It can match string containing "entre" as first street name.

Comment: Your welcome - If you have exceptions strings that can't be parsed by this pattern just let me know. Otherwise you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can just use

```
([\w ]*?) entre ([\w ]*) y ([\w ]*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK4uW4/2)

No need to use more `entre`s since we are using greedy matching.

Replacing with `$1/$2-$3` we get:

```
av cordoba/medrano-gascon
esmeralda/av rivadavia-lavalle
av cor1doba entre/rios-suipac2ha
monroe/aizpurra-av de los constituyentes
```

Comment: That's correct, but the string "av cor1doba entre/rios-suipacha" must be "av cor1doba/entre rios-suipacha"

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try it without the whitespaces?

```
([\w ]*[^'entre']{1})entre([\w ]*) y ([\w ]*)
```